# How to Write Text On a Image with Centered Position C#

Tags: c#

How can i change the position of the "hello and test" string in the green box to the center position in an image ? I want to place the position of the hello string and the test in the middle of an image (which I marked the red circle), the link to the image> https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/I1hTWNS.png

I have added a "center" alignment but the position of the string is still to the left of the image.

```
public void drawString()    
{    
    string firstText = "Hello" + Environment.NewLine + "Test";    
    string imageFilePath = directory + name + "\\Desktop\\plain.jpg";    
    Bitmap newBitmap;  

    using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath))//load the image file    
    {    
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))    
        {    
            using (Font arialFont = new Font("Arial", 26, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point))
            {    
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, ClientSize.Width - 10, ClientSize.Height - 10);    

                StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();    
                sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;    
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;    

                graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFont, Brushes.Red, rect, sf);    
                graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Green, rect);    
            }    
        } 

        newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap);    
    }    

    newBitmap.Save(imageFilePath);//save the image file    
    newBitmap.Dispose();    
}
```

I have added a "center" alignment but the position of the string is still to the left of the image.

Comment: Why don't you use the bitmap size? Like `Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);`

Comment: sorry, I just tried it for the first time

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko great, it's working 
https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/I1iaKZw.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You text is indeed centered in the rectangle you created. The problem is that the rectangle you based it off the `ClientSize` `Height` and `Width` which come from the control you are inside.

What you want to use is the current `Bitmap` properties for `Height` and `Width`.

instead of :

```
 Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, ClientSize.Width - 10, ClientSize.Height - 10);
```

you want :

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
```